# " ’ ” (apostrophy) gets replaced to “apos;” while update

Tags: escaping, xss, sybase, sap-ase

I get a field in XML format lets say `Niraj's Car`.

We normally just pick up this value from XML tag and insert it into a variable and the update into our database table.
But for some reason the string gets replaced to `Niraj&apos; car`. 
I tried update table with `Niraj's Car` manually the update is correct.
However, for some reason when we get from XML format, dynamically i see `Niraj&apos; Car` in the table.
Strange - could this be because of escaping characters?

Comment: In XML `Niraj's Car` and `Niraj&apos; Car` are equivalent. If you are getting `&apos;` in your database then, presumably, the problem is that you aren't using a proper XML parser. You've provided no code, so its hard to tell for sure.

Comment: XML snippet example : <Name> Niraj's Car </Name>

My code just picks up this value from XML and put it in a variable say Test var then update tableCustomer set Name = Test where Id = 123.
And in my table I get Niraj&apos; Car.

But if update manually the same thing i.e update tableCustomer set Name = Test where Id = 123, I get corrrect value viz Niraj's Car.

Comment: You've **still** provided no code, so see my previous comment. Vague descriptions about what code does are not the same as code.

Comment: I agree, but it is little tough for me to do that.
But I now know the reason why ' got replaced with &apos; - it is because of I extract the required text from XML with XMLEXTRACT sybase function. And this function internally replaces the string.
Do you know any other function which could overcome this bug?

Comment: @Quentin here's the query where I get ' replaced with &apos;
select XML = convert(varchar(1677),xmlextract('/TAGNEW'),column_name,option 'xmlerror = null')
from table_name
where ID = 123
--column_name has XML text containing ' in a text starting with tag TABNEW.

Comment: The point of xmlextract is to give you XML… and what you are getting is XML. If you want text then don't use xmlextract (or use xmlextract and then run the result through an xml parser).